# Excel pasting data issue

Tags: excel, graph

Hi all i have been conducting research using JNNS creating neural networks.

I have collected my results inside a result file and wish to create graphs with them to clearly present my findings in a report.

My issue is when pasting the result file contents (expected outputs and then actual outputs) into excel the whole set of results goes into the A1 column instead of spreading across multiple rows

Does anyone know how i would go about fixing this issue?

Example to aid question:

## 1.1 Expected result / actual result

0, 0,  1,  0

0.02501,  0.00013,  0.99952,  0

and pasting this into excel does this:

https://gyazo.com/38c089ebcfaca7b85d31caacd3e950f9

instead of this:

https://gyazo.com/22f1527df18e811871e53402cea4ab2f

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your data is in a CSV format, do you have notepad++?

if you do open it there and click on the show all characters, i wanna know what do you have at the end of your lines CR or LF...

Comment: it has both CR and LF?

Comment: From what i see in your last screenshot it seem, you dont have commas

seem you data is separated by spaces, if that is the case you can use the import tool, go to data tab, and clock on get external data from text, when the dialog comes up, specify "space" as your separator and click import that should get your data there...

Comment: Thank you for the help, there is a strange issue where i need to import "Break lines" to separate columns buts the data in the txt files isnt clearly ordered so the break lines cause this issue:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to OmarQA for the help, i needed to paste my data into a text file, replace all spaces with commas using the replace tool, then import data from text on excel and use comma as data separation and it solved the issue!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It might be that excel's not recognizing the proper delimiter when you're pasting you data. On Excel, select the cell with the entire text (in your picture, cell A1) and go to the Data tab. Look for a button called "Convert text to columns" or something like that. It will open a new window asking you for parameters (delimiters, if comma is a decimal separator, etc) and it gives you a preview of how your data is going to look like with that setting. Just mess around a little bit and you should get your data good to go. Looking at your picture, it might be possible that you didn't select "tab" as a delimiter.